# Optimal way to find pairs in a list of strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of Unique strings in a list. I need to find the pairing elements. A Pairing element is one which matches either of following conditions

1. strings A, B are a pair if they A end in "_N" and B end in "_P" or Vice versa eg: ABCD_N & ABCD_P are a pair
2. strings A, B are a pair if an occurrence of "N" is replaced by "P" will give you string B or vice versa.
   Eg: ABNX,ABPX are both pairs

Right now I am looping the list and searching for its corresponding pair in rest of list and pairing them which is at least O(n^2) and my list of string can be huge up to a million

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<list.Count && j != i; j++)
    {
        if(list[i].EndsWith("_N") || list[j].EndsWith("_P"))
        {
            //Call method to find corresponding pair for this string;       O(n)
            //Call my processPairsmethod()
        }
    }
}
```

Other option is Regex which I can leverage for ending in _N & _P condition but not sure how to get a regex for second condition.

PS: No duplicates exist in the  `list`

Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Doesn't the second condition already cover the first one?

Comment: Anyway, if it's guaranteed that the list doesn't have duplicates, you're better off using a `HashSet`. Now, can the elements contain multiple `N`s or `P`s? If so, do you replace just one occurrence or all of them?

Comment: Yes...elements can contain multiple N or P. In that case, we should replace all of them and check corresponding string name in residual list.

Comment: Nope the first condition is just looking at End of string with "_N" or "_P" it doesn't bother if other part of string has a N or P.  
The Second condition covers first one ONLY if string contains no N except the last _N

Answer (score 0):

If you know the strings are unique, you could just create a function that creates a unique key, e.g. replacing both N and P with a non-existing char (like '*'):

```
// matches one single "N" or "P", that will be replaced by a single "*"
var rx = new Regex("N|P", RegexOptions.Compiled);

// pairs will be a list of string[2] arrays
var pairs = list.Select(s => new { Original = s, Key = rx.Replace(s, "*") })
  .ToLookup(obj => obj.Key)
  // each grp should be of length 2. In this select, validity checks should
  // be performed
  .Select(grp => grp.Select(obj => obj.Original).ToArray())
  .ToList();
```

Using `ToLookup` should give you better performance: it roughly should go as O(n), because lookup searches would be (around) O(1).

Bear in mind the code is untested.

Comment: what about ANNBC and APBCP ? This will make them match while they clearly don't

Answer (score 0):

First your algo is flawed because you assume that strings ending with _N and _P would be pairing, but what about ABC_N and ABCDE_P ? They dont pair. (different length)

What you have to do is to iterate over each string over each character, and have only one character that differ, which will be N for one string and P for the other.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j=i + 1;j<list.Count && j != i; j++) // you dont need to start at j = 0
    {
        int a = 0;
        while (list[i][a] == list[j][a])
             a++;
        if ((list[i][a] == 'N' && list[j][a] == 'P') || (list[i][a] == 'P' && list[j][a] == 'N') {
             while (list[i][a] == list[j][a])
                 a++;
              if (list[i][a] == list[j][a] && list[j][a] == '\0')
                   // both list items match
                  //Call my 
         }
            
        }
    }
}
```

## O(N) Algorithm

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
     // replace N by P in the string
     if (map.ContainsKey(list[i]))
         processPairsmethod(map[list[i]], list[i]);
     else {
         int a = 0;
         while (list[i][a]) {
               if (list[i][a] == 'N' || 'P') {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list[i]);
                    sb[a] = list[i][a] ^ 'N' ^ 'P'; // will replace N by P and P by N thanks to xoring operation as N ^ N ^ P = P
                    String key = sb.ToString();
                    map[key] = list[i]; // map["ANBC "] = "APBC", now you just need to check for the key.
               }
               a++;
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: I am handling the length Part in validation. Here I tried to give you a gist of the core problem. Assume this logic only comes after the length validation

Comment: then u can follow this algo anyways, also start at i+1 to save time with j

Comment: this is still `O(n^2)K` K=max length of the strings